# Why does android emulator running Oreo crash when FireFox is running on Windows 10?

Tags: android-emulator

I created android emulator with the following settings:

```
Name: Pixel_API_27_Oreo

CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\.android\avd\Pixel_API_27_Oreo.avd

Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 27)

Skin: pixel_silver

SD Card: 512M

fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 27

tag.id: google_apis_playstore

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.camera.front: emulated

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel API 27 Oreo

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.ramSize: 1536

PlayStore.enabled: true

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.cpu.ncore: 4

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1920

vm.heapSize: 228

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-27\google_apis_playstore\x86\

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: virtualscene

AvdId: Pixel_API_27_Oreo

hw.lcd.density: 420

hw.arc: false

hw.device.hash2: MD5:55acbc835978f326788ed66a5cd4c9a7

fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no

fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google Play

runtime.network.latency: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 2G

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

If the emulator is started while FireFox v 67.0 is running then it crashes immediately.

**What I've Tried**
I can start an emulator image running x86 Nougat or Marshmallow with no problem.

Here are the errors from android studio:

```
5:42 PM Emulator: Fatal: createDIB: CreateDIBSection failed (300x300, format: 6) ((null):0, (null))

5:42 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740286 (0xC0000602)

5:43 PM Emulator: terminate called without an active exception

5:44 PM Emulator: Warning: QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread ((null):0, (null))

5:44 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 3
```

If FireFox isn't running then when the emulator starts it gives this error (keep in mind this is from a fresh image, never been started before).

[image: android oreo with google play]

If I do anything on the phone then I get a black screen on the emulator.
If I start the image again then the emulator screen is black/blank and I see the following message in Android Studio

[image: please accept]

But there is no message on the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to the AVD (Android Virtual Device manager) and selected the image and dropped the list and wiped the user data (even though this one has never been started before.
[image: wipe user data]

Then I restarted the image again after about 1 minute android started and I saw the following:

[image: accept debugging]